# Visual Studio Intellisense Can Find References But Build Fails Due To Missing References

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-debugging

I'm currently running into an issue (on Visual Studio 2022) where the test project within my solution is referencing a few other projects in my solution; however, trying to build the test project results in errors for these project references. Even more interesting is that this test project used to be working fine.

So far I've:

- Double checked the pathing of the project dll's being referenced
- Removed and re-added the project references.
- Editing the file, Intellisense is able to find the references, but when building the console output shows errors.
- Cleaned the solution
- Seen recommendations online of clearing the Temp folder and *AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.x\ComponentModelCache* for my user account and have done so

None of this has helped. Any guidance on what to research or things to try/insight to the problem would be much appreciated!

Thank you

-Austin

EDIT 1 (7/5/2022)
[Error List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoTXu.png)

The error seem to resolve themselves when I click on them from the Error Lists (after viewing the place in the file where the reference error is occurring, the error disappears after a few seconds, removing it from the Error List and also the removing the red squiggle underline). However, the error does not actually resolve as there are still the same reference errors when trying to Build the test project.

For example, STEP.Entities is a project in the solution that is referenced by the test project. However, the test project can't find the referred Entities project.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more error info from the error list and then we can give more help. You can try to Clear All NuGet Cache under Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General and restore the pacakges to the latest version.

Comment: Hi @JingmiaoXu-MSFT , I've added a picture of the error list. The behavior seems to be that Intellisense *at first* can't find the reference (giving an error in the Error List and showing a red squiggle underline). Then after clicking on the error in the error list to view the place in the file where the error is occurring, the error seems to resolve itself and be removed from the Error List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized the issue was caused by packages used in the other projects of the solution were targeting different .NET versions than the same packages within the Test project.

- (Firstly, to determine this I went to Tools > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > select MSBuild Project Build Verbosity as Diagnostic. (I believe this generates more a detailed report of the status to the Output Console when building projects)).

Specifically, a lot of these packages in my test project were targeting .NET v 4.8 as opposed to v4.7.2 being targeted by packages in the other projects, and the Test project itself and other projects targeting v4.7.2. I updated my Test project to target v4.8 and everything works/references can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem recently with a project from GitHub, my best sugestion is to try checking the version you are using and maybe select an older version of the said references.
It took me a while to get it done but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked around this with following `global.json` in the root of my drive:

C:\global.json

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature",
    "allowPrerelease": false
  }
}
```

Or there might be a `global.json` in your solution somewhere, with a .NET SDK version that doesn't exist...

To list all installed .NET sdks on your computer, run

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

and pick the correct version.